# Appropriate Scala Collection similar to Python Dictionary

Tags: scala

I have an algorithm that iteratively returns `(key, value)`. What I want to do is store these results in a structure such that if the `key` does not exist, it will add it and the corresponding `value`. Now, if the key exists, it will append the `value` to an existing array of values.

In python, I can do this using a python dictionary with this format:

```
dict = {'key1': [val1, val2, val3],
        'key2': [val4, val5], 
        'key3': [val6], ... }
```

and simply do:

```
if key in dict.keys():
    dict[key].append(value)
else:
    dict[key] = [value]
```

How do I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
scala> def insert[K,V](k: K, v: V, m: Map[K, List[V]]): Map[K, List[V]] = {
     | if (m contains k) m + (k -> (m(k) :+ v))
     | else m + (k -> List(v)) }
insert: [K, V](k: K, v: V, m: Map[K,List[V]])Map[K,List[V]]

scala> insert('b', 23, Map('b' -> List(2)))
res30: Map[Char,List[Int]] = Map(b -> List(2, 23))

scala> insert('b', 23, Map('c' -> List(2)))
res31: Map[Char,List[Int]] = Map(c -> List(2), b -> List(23))
```

---

Or, incorporating Sergey's very fine suggestion:

```
def insert[K,V](k: K, v: V, m: Map[K, List[V]]): Map[K, List[V]] =
  m + (k -> (m.getOrElse(k, List()) :+ v))
```

Comment: What about another `insert` implementation `m + (k -> (m.getOrElse(k, List()) :+ v))` ?

Comment: @jwvh, does this method creates a new Map every time it is called?

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao, yes. But Scala collections are implemented such that this is low cost (they're persistent - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure). They share most of their structure between versions. Scala also has mutable collections, so you can ape the Python approach if that's preferred.  The Scala "style" is to use immutable ones, though.

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao, yes.  The FP preference is for immutable data structures, created as needed and destroyed (garbage collected) when abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the powerful typesystem in Scala, you can do this in a more general manner:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

case class CollectingMap[K, V, C[_]](underlying: Map[K, C[V]] = Map[K, C[V]]()) {
  def add(key: K, value: V)(implicit s: Monoid[C[V]], a: Applicative[C]): CollectingMap[K, V, C] = {
    // Either get the old value from the underyling map or the empty collection, provided by the Monoid[C[V]]
    val oldValue = underlying.get(key).getOrElse(mzero[C[V]])
    // Append the old vlaue to the new value, provided by Monoid |+|.
    // value.point[C] is provided by the Applicative, which allows us to lift the value into the collection C.
    val newValue = oldValue |+| value.point[C]
    // return the updated value, wrapped into CollectingMap again.
    CollectingMap(underlying.updated(key, newValue))
  }
}
```

Example:

```
val m = CollectingMap[Int, String, List]()
m.add(2, "bar").add(2, "foo")
// => res4: CollectingMap[Int,String,List] = CollectingMap(Map(2 -> List(bar, foo)))
```